# How to make a stopwatch timer

Tags: ios, swift, timer, swift5

For some reason the stopwatch looks to be alright, but when compared to the real deal it goes way too fast. I don't understand what I should do. Is it the timeInterval that I should change? I would like it to show millisecond, second and minutes, but everything I try just makes it worse.. Thank you

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var minutes: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var seconds: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var milliSecondsLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var resetButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var pauseButton: UIButton!

    // Variables
    var timer = Timer()
    var time: Int = 0
    var running: Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        roundButtons()

    }

    @IBAction func resetTimer(_ sender: Any) {
        timer.invalidate()
        time = 0
        updateUI()
        running = false
    }

    @IBAction func startTimer(_ sender: Any) {
        if running {
            return
        } else {
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(timerDidEnd), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            running = true
        }

    }

    @IBAction func pauseTimer(_ sender: Any) {
        timer.invalidate()
        running = false
    }


    func roundButtons() {
        resetButton.layer.cornerRadius = resetButton.frame.height / 2
        startButton.layer.cornerRadius = startButton.frame.height / 2
        pauseButton.layer.cornerRadius = pauseButton.frame.height / 2
    }

    @objc func timerDidEnd() {
        time += 1
        updateUI()
    }

    func updateUI() {

        var min: Int
        var sec: Int
        var mil: Int

        min = time / (60*60)
        sec = (time/60)%60
        mil = time & 60

        minutes.text = String(min)
        seconds.text = String(sec)
        milliSecondsLabel.text = String(mil)
    }
}
```

Comment: You should never rely on a timer to measure elapsed time. Just store your start date and check the elapsed timeinterval since now to update the UI

Comment: Btw you don’t need to update the UI 100 times per second. You can set it to 1/30 of a second. It would be enough for displaying it to the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest two things:

1. Don’t try to count the time elapsed yourself. Capture the start time and calculate the elapsed time from that. You can use `Date` method [`timeIntervalSince`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1779636-timeintervalsince), or, because that's not guaranteed to return monotonically increasing values, use [`CACurrentMediaTime`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/1395996-cacurrentmediatime?language=occ), like below.
2. Rather than having a timer with an arbitrary 100 updates per second, instead use a [`CADisplayLink`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink), which is optimally timed for device screen refresh rates.

E.g.:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var minutesLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var milliSecondsLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var resetButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var pauseButton: UIButton!

    // Variables
    private weak var displayLink: CADisplayLink?
    private var startTime: CFTimeInterval?
    private var elapsed: CFTimeInterval = 0
    private var priorElapsed: CFTimeInterval = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setFonts()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        roundButtons()
    }

    @IBAction func resetTimer(_ sender: Any) {
        stopDisplayLink()
        elapsed = 0
        priorElapsed = 0
        updateUI()
    }

    @IBAction func startTimer(_ sender: Any) {
        if displayLink == nil {
            startDisplayLink()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func pauseTimer(_ sender: Any) {
        priorElapsed += elapsed
        elapsed = 0
        displayLink?.invalidate()
    }
}

private extension ViewController {
    func startDisplayLink() {
        startTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
        let displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(handleDisplayLink(_:)))
        displayLink.add(to: .main, forMode: .common)
        self.displayLink = displayLink
    }

    func stopDisplayLink() {
        displayLink?.invalidate()
    }

    @objc func handleDisplayLink(_ displayLink: CADisplayLink) {
        guard let startTime = startTime else { return }
        elapsed = CACurrentMediaTime() - startTime
        updateUI()
    }

    func updateUI() {
        let totalElapsed = elapsed + priorElapsed

        let hundredths = Int((totalElapsed * 100).rounded())
        let (minutes, hundredthsOfSeconds) = hundredths.quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy: 60 * 100)
        let (seconds, milliseconds) = hundredthsOfSeconds.quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy: 100)

        minutesLabel.text = String(minutes)
        secondsLabel.text = String(format: "%02d", seconds)
        milliSecondsLabel.text = String(format: "%02d", milliseconds)
    }

    func roundButtons() {
        resetButton.layer.cornerRadius = resetButton.bounds.height / 2
        startButton.layer.cornerRadius = startButton.bounds.height / 2
        pauseButton.layer.cornerRadius = pauseButton.bounds.height / 2
    }

    func setFonts() {
        minutesLabel.font = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: minutesLabel.font.pointSize, weight: .regular)
        secondsLabel.font = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: secondsLabel.font.pointSize, weight: .regular)
        milliSecondsLabel.font = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: milliSecondsLabel.font.pointSize, weight: .regular)
    }
}
```

That yields:

[image]

---

Completely unrelated, but anything dependent upon the size of views (e.g. the corner rounding) really belongs in [`viewDidLayoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews), not `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: For discussion of concern regarding monotonically increasing values, see the [`CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1543542-cfabsolutetimegetcurrent).

Comment: Thank you Rob, a lot mor information then I expected, learned a lot from it.